# Binding a String to a Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have a model, something like:

```
public class PageModel {
  public string PropA { get; set; }
  public string PropB { get; set; }      
  public Type DataType { get; set; }

  public PageModel() {}
  ...
}
```

My view then has something like:

```
...
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  <li>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PropA) <br /> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PropA)</li>
  <li>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PropB) <br /> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PropB)</li>
  <li>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.DataType) <br /> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DataType)</li>
  <li><input type="submit" /></li>
}
...
```

Using default model binding, the String properties get set correctly, but the Type property ends up as NULL, even when provided with a valid Type string representation (e.g. "System.String" or "System.Boolean").

Any recommendations on how to get this Type property bound correctly? A type-specific custom model binder seems like the best approach, but I wouldn't want to rewrite the binding of PropA and PropB.

Comment: Why not override the default model binder and include a call to `base.CreateModel`?

Comment: Overriding CreateModel() didn't get me anywhere, but I was able to override BindProperty() for the behavior I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Ant P's comment, I implemented a model binder which inherits from DefaultModelBinder, and overrode BindProperty()

See http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx#s11-custom-binding-with-only-few-properties for details.

Thanks Ant P!